# ruby on rails how to show (userid and password ) login validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

it is my login application .please anyone can explain me how can i check login validations

pbl01/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
:registrations => 'users/registrations'
}
resources :import,only: [:index,:create]
root 'root#index'

# For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

pbl01/app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

def new

end

def create
authorized_user=User.authenticate(params[:userid],params[:password])

   if authorized_user
      flash[:notice] = "Wow Welcome again, you logged in as"

else
  flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"
  flash[:color]= "invalid"
  render "new"  
   end
end
```

pbl01/app/models/user.rb

```
require 'csv'
class User < ApplicationRecord
validates :userid, :presence => true,
validates :password, :presence => true,


devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

def email_required?
false
end
def self.import(file)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

  users = find_by(userid: row["userid"]) || new

  users.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*updatable_attributes)
  users.password= row["password"]

  users.save!
end
end


def self.updatable_attributes
["userid", "name", "email"]
 end
end
```

pbl01/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
 <% if @user.errors.any? %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :userid %><br />
<%= f.text_field :userid, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
<% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
  <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
<% end %>
</div>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
</div>
<% end -%>

<div class="actions">
 <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
 </div>
 <% end %>

 <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I believe you should change to something like this.

    <h2>Log in</h2>
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: 
      session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <% if @user.errors.any? %>
         <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
           <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
         <% end %>
      <% end %>
     <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :userid %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :userid, autofocus: true %>
     </div>

     <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>

    </div>

   <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
    <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
   <% end %>



    <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
     </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```